# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/lib/security/cacerts: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, security, xmpp, asmack, quickblox

I´m really stuck with this error and I have no idea how to fix it. 
I´m trying to connect to XMMP server, I can connect and users can send and receive the messages, but I get an error:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/lib/security/cacerts: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

the code is:

```
 public void startChat(String buddyLogin) {
        this.friendLogin = buddyLogin;
        TAG = "ChatService.startChat";
        SmackAndroid.init(ctx);      
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() { 
                XMPPConnection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;
                Connection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;
                Log.d(TAG, "CHAT_SERVER "+CHAT_SERVER); 
                try { 
                       config = new AndroidConnectionConfiguration(CHAT_SERVER);

                       SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN");
                       config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true); 

                       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                           config.setTruststoreType("AndroidCAStore");
                           config.setTruststorePassword(null);
                         //  config.setTruststorePath(null);
                       } else {
                        config.setTruststoreType("BKS");
                         /*  String path = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
                           if (path == null)
                               path = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "etc"
                                   + File.separator + "security" + File.separator
                                   + "cacerts.bks";
                           config.setTruststorePath(path);*/
                       }            

                       connection = new XMPPConnection(config);     

                      connection.connect();
                    connection.login(chatLogin, QuickBloxUtils.password);
                    chatManager = connection.getChatManager();
                    chat = chatManager.createChat(friendLogin, messageListener);
                    chatManager.addChatListener(chatManagerListener);
                } catch (XMPPException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error al intentar conectar.", e);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

I´m just wondering the error is because it doesn´t find the struststoretype.
But I don´t know how to solve it.
Any help ,please?

Comment: I had this problem. I deleted the folder created programmatically and created it manually and the problem solved!!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but could you explain me a bit more, please?

Which folders do you mean?
I didn´t create any folder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user2468699 did you find the solution?